# How to get the date of last updated post or page and put it in the footer

Tags: updates, date

I want to show in the footer that my WordPress site has been updated recently, how can I show it on the the footer? There are codes that I find where they put the last update on the post, but I want it to be whenever a post and a page is updated or even when an image is uploaded and not just inside a post.

I'm also using a multisite so I want it to be on the footer of every sites that I build.

Comment: you can use the function `get_posts` with multiple post type : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: This is so abstract that can be answered with multiple answers and still not be able to solve every aspect.

Comment: Its not clear, do you mean when WordPress is updated or when content in a page or post is updated ?

Comment: Which of the examples you found you tried and what specifically was insufficient for your needs?